# Vertically center a div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a problem with vertically centering a simple div.
It always give `margin-top="0px"`

The vertical centering is the same as the horizontal centering and that works perfect.

(it is necessary to center it in javascript for further development)

Any solutions?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var width1 = $("body").width();
  var width2 = $("#main").width();
  var height1 = $("body").height();
  var height2 = $("#main").height();
  var centerw = (width1 - width2) / 2;
  var centerh = (height1 - height2) / 2;
  $("#main").css("margin-left", centerw + "px");
  $("#main").css("margin-top", centerh + "px");
});
$(window).resize(function() {
  var width1 = $("body").width();
  var width2 = $("#main").width();
  var height1 = $("body").height();
  var height2 = $("#main").height();
  var centerw = (width1 - width2) / 2;
  var centerh = (height1 - height2) / 2;
  $("#main").css("margin-left", centerw + "px");
  $("#main").css("margin-top", centerh + "px");
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#main {
  width: 400px;
  height: 600px;
  background-color: gray;
}
```

```html
<body>

  <div id="main">

  </div>

</body>
```

Comment: You do know you can pass an object to [`.css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css/#css-properties), hence setting multiple CSS value in one shot, right?

Comment: Protip: `margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto` will center a block.

Comment: how do you seperate the 2 css-values when using multiple? Like .css("margin-top","value1","margin-left","value2")?

Comment: Maybe this is a clearing issue. Try removing the `float: left` css declaration. Also, as protip above, to center horizontally you will be able to do `margin: 0 auto;` on `#main` in your case.

Comment: give an object to the css function as an argument, like this: `.css({'margin-top': 'value1', 'margin-left': 'value2'})`

Comment: If you add height:100% to your universal selector, it works: http://jsfiddle.net/vz9ym7ef/1/

Comment: it worked with the "height: 100%" and removing the "float: left" on *

Comment: Why are you using JS to do this instead of letting CSS do the work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Chrome i didn't had a problem with your code, only in firefox it doesn't work.

The problem is that the body is the same height as the box, you can set height for body as 100% or use *$(window).height();* instead *$("body").height();*

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ojz6dew6/1/)

```html
<!DOCTYPE  html>
<html>
 <head>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
  <script>
   $(document).ready(function() {
     var width1 = $(window).width();
     var width2 = $("#main").width();
     var height1 = $(window).height();
     var height2 = $("#main").height();
     var centerw = (width1 - width2) / 2;
     var centerh = (height1 - height2) / 2;
     console.log(width1+" " +width2 + " " + height1 + " " + height2);
     $("#main").css("margin-left", centerw + "px");
     $("#main").css("margin-top", centerh + "px");
   });
   $(window).resize(function() {
     var width1 = $("body").width();
     var width2 = $("#main").width();
     var height1 = $("body").height();
     var height2 = $("#main").height();
     var centerw = (width1 - width2) / 2;
     var centerh = (height1 - height2) / 2;
     $("#main").css("margin-left", centerw + "px");
     $("#main").css("margin-top", centerh + "px");
   });    
  </script>
  
  <style>   
   #main {
     width: 400px;
     height: 600px;
     background-color: gray;
   }
  </style>
 </head>
 <body>
   <div id="main"></div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I use google chrome v45.0 , and firefox v40.0, it doesn't work on either by changing "body" to window.

Comment: @DNA, test this: http://jsfiddle.net/vz9ym7ef/4/ It should work. Also, instead document ready, use $(window).load .... When you need to calculate elements heights/widths, you need content loaded, not just DOM to be ready.... also, notice removal of redundant * selector....

Comment: Have you <!DOCTYPE  html> in first line? Becouse in my case without this it doesn't work, with this is ok. But in chrome i don't need that line.

Comment: @Artur Ziomek: I do have a doctype

Comment: @DNA: It's realy weird. But i'm happy it's working for you with $(window).load

Answer (score 0):

You don't need Javascript for that as long as you know your box's dimensions.

```
#main {
    height: 600px;
    background-color: gray;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -300px;
    margin-left: -200px;
    width: 400px;
}
```

This is how you do your math :

margin-left = -width / 2

margin-top = -height / 2

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/)

**Note:** never use `*` selector in css, especially if you are going to apply 10 properties like in your example

Comment: the width and height will changed later for responsiveness and they will be in % on mobile, so i cannot do the math myself when they change the window on mobile-sized browsers

Comment: then try to adapt your javascript with the method I explained here (adjust the margins), I am pretty sure it will work fine cross-browser. Plus, there are only two variables instead of four